# Azure - Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net-core, web-config, azure-web-app-service, kudu

i have a situation here. I would to publish one of my 'test' .net core application (.net core 3.1) to see how Azure platfrom works and there is a problem after publishing web app is running then i have an error: "currently unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500".
Actions taken:

- I've run .dll in  Kudu console error description : "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
- I was trying to change web.config but error is the same

(web.config after edit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SportsStore.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

I found a lot of topics about this issue but it wasn't help in my case. Any sugesstions ?

Comment: What process did you use to publish?

Comment: I've published an application by VS -> publish -> App service ->create new (profile) according to Adam Freeman book "Asp.net core mvc 2". But i'm not sure if i corectly understood your question coz i'm new in Azure.

Comment: Can your program run normally locally? It is recommended to try to deploy using `git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I think this `500` error should be a deployment failure error.

**At the end of the answer, there is a suggested solution to try, it is recommended to try.**

In order to quickly locate and solve the problem, I recommend using [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889091/concurrently-js-application-pipeline-install-and-build-hangs-express-js-for-ser/62926345#62926345) for [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment). More error logs can be viewed in Action like pic.

[image]

If the above method does not help you locate the specific cause of the failure, then I suggest you use `Diagnose and solve problems` to troubleshoot the problem. Search the search box for `Collect .NET Profiler Trace`,

[image]

Then you can click `Collect Profile Trace`, and wait system generate a report. Click the link, you will open a new page and see more details about the webapp.

[image]

***Suggest a trial plan (specific problems need specific solutions)***

1. Try by modifying the `web.config` file.

[image]

[image]

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="YourErrorPage.aspx" mode="Off">
<error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalErrorPage.aspx"/>
```

You also can [create log in your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-logs), then you can see more details.

2. When you are sure that there is no problem with your program, it is recommended to re-create a new `resource group` or choose another `region` to try to redeploy. If this error still occurs, it is recommended to `raise a support ticket` in the portal.

**Sum up:**

1. First of all, it is recommended to use git for continuous deployment to troubleshoot the operating environment or problems that occur in the release operation.
2. Use tools to troubleshoot the root cause, if it is really impossible, you can raise a ticket for support.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've used your solution and now app run correctly. I've pushed project by git and this helped. So sory for my late reply :)!