# Azure App Service - Request Diagnostics reveals HTTPS on port 80

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I created an Azure App Service. Deployed it via a develops pipeline.

Basically, this service is broken, and im trying to troubleshoot it.

During my investigation using the Request Diagnostics blade/tool, i learned that the request url is using HTTPS with port 80.

Does this mean i tried making an invalid request?

Comment: Hi, @AlvinfromDiaspar, if my answer helps, would you mind accept as the answer for others to refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some ways for troubleshooting web app breken:

1. You could find out the error logs in kudu: `yourwebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` --> *LogFiles* --> *eventlog.xml*, which file only be created when your web app broken.
   [image]
2. A useful tool you mentioned in your question also helps. The steps for diagnostics is: Click **Availability and Performance**--> click **Web App Down**.
   [image]
   [image]

---

3. Here is [a solution about troubleshooting `.net-core` web application broken using **Diagnostic tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053677/azure-unhandled-exception-system-io-filenotfoundexception/63065704#63065704). As you can see, JAVA and PHP also supported. see the created **Profiler Trace** in kudu: `yourwebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`--> **data**--> **DaaS**--> **logs**--> **yourwebapp**.
   [image]