# HTTP Error 500.37 - ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit - Still not resolved after increasing Startup Time Limit

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, config

I am attempting to deploy new services to Azure App Service and am getting the following error message on the services:

[image: Error 500.37 screenshot]

After doing some research, it seems the most common approach to this problem is to increase the startupTimeLimit, which I have done a couple times and is not resolving this issue.

Here is the section of the web.config file containing the startupTimeLimit increase:

```
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TemplateService.Api.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" startupTimeLimit="900">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
```

I originally attempted to increase to 300 seconds but that didn't fix it, so I went ahead and upped it to 900 seconds just to see if I could get past this error (which I didn't).

Are there any other ways to resolve this issue if this increase is not fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

*Please restore your web.config to its original state. The settings of*

```
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
```

*are not required.*

**I can't tell you the reason directly, but I can help you find the error log of the problem. When you see the error log, you can search for it by google to solve the problem.**

## Troubleshooting

#### Method 1.

Add `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` on portal, not `web.config` file. It will show more details in page.

[image]

#### Method 2.

Add `stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"` in `web.config` file. And you can find log file in `scm` site.

For more details, you can read: [Enabling ASP.NET Core stdout log (Windows Server)](http://docs.lacunasoftware.com/en-us/articles/amplia/on-premises/windows/enable-stdout-log.html).

***If you also can't find the reason, you need to use method 3.***

#### Method 3.

① You can `Collect .NET Profiler Trace` on portal.

*For more details, you can refer my answer in below post.*

[Azure - Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053677/azure-unhandled-exception-system-io-filenotfoundexception/63065704#63065704)

[image]

② And you also can check application event logs.

[image]