# Node js app error didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. on Azure app service linux (not docker)

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-appservice

Nodejs app works locally and also works on app service if deployed to Azure app service Linux directly from visual studio but does not work when deployed using azure devops

Artifact files and folders using visual studio -

```
config 
demo 
dist 
src
gulpfile.babel.js 
node_modules 
package-lock.json 
package.json 
postcss.config.js 
web.config
node_modules.tar.gz  
oryx-manifest.toml
```

Artifact files using Azure devops -

```
config 
demo 
dist 
src
gulpfile.babel.js 
node_modules 
package-lock.json 
package.json 
postcss.config.js 
web.config
```

When I am trying to deploy using azure devops App service deploy task deployment works but URL is not working and logs errors are -

```
container test didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container     logs for debugging.
2020-09-12T05:37:46.165Z INFO  - Stopping site because it failed during startup.
2020-09-12T05:53:51.152Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-09-12T05:53:51.153Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 1861:8080 --name  -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=test  -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=test.azurewebsites.net -e
```

I don't have any docker-file , if ports is the issue, then why its works when I publish to Azure app service using visual studio?

These are my mentioned ports

```
serve({
port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
open: true,
server: {
baseDir: 'src'
},
```

Comment: Do you have a `PORT` environment variable? Without it, won't your application just listen to port 3000?

Comment: I did add port = 8080 in Azure app service application settings but no luck

Comment: @Mureinik Did you mean anything different ?

Comment: @megha Azure webapp only support port 80/443(http/https). Now, your webapp doesn't work after deployed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now what you are doing is to publish the webapp through `devops`. The phenomenon is that it cannot be accessed normally. The error message prompts that `container test didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.`

**Similar related posts should be helpful to you.**

[Struggling to upload my node.js application to azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542349/struggling-to-upload-my-node-js-application-to-azure/63560215#63560215)

Because the project is normal locally, we are now troubleshooting the problem.

1. Because azure app services only supports ports `80` and `443`. So check if only one port is enabled in the program. Such as configuring `port: process.env.PORT || 3000`.
2. It is recommended to [use git for continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment) to test whether your webapp project can run normally in azure app services

If continuous deployment using Git is successful:

1. If git continuous deployment can replace your deployment method requirements, and the project can start normally, then your problem will be solved.
2. But if you must want deploy apps by using devops, there may be errors when configuring release.

If you are really not sure where there is an error, you can [raise a support ticket on the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). Let an official engineer assist you in checking logs and troubleshooting problems.