# Error on npm start on Azure - EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying to get a nodejs app running on Azure (which runs perfectly fine on Heroku).

After running npm start on the app, the following error happens:

```
Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1 - Local (0.0.0.0:56256)
    at internalConnect (net.js:907:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:301:12)
    at net.js:998:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1'
}
```

I've tried setting various ports which are free, but no matter what, I get this error.

Comment: Judging from your error message, your problem lies in the port conflict. Generally, as long as you are running normally locally and deploying with git, there will be no problems. It is recommended to use the `Linux` operating environment.

Comment: It is running on a Linux web app

Comment: When you deploy it by git, you can find error/logs in Action.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I know that your current program runs normally in Heroku, and it runs very well locally.

But what I want to tell you is that in azure webapp, there is no need to execute the npm start command to start the webapp. After you pass the deployment, you can set the Startup Command in the portal to start your application. For general nodejs projects, the **startup command** is `npx serve -s`.

*So you said that the execution of npm start produces an error. If you execute this start command in kudu, it is inappropriate.*

If an error occurs when running locally, such as `connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1-Local (0.0.0.0:56256)`, it is recommended that you use `netstat -ano|findstr "56256"` to check which process uses the port and deal with.

**PRIVIOUS**

You need to macke sure use `process.env.PORT || 3000` in your project. And you need to know, the port in azure webapp just support `80` and `443`. So in your project, So in your code, there can only be one `PORT` value. After deployed, `443` and `80` will work.

And you can run your app perfectly on `HeroKu`. So I suggest you upload your code to github.

Then you can [deploy your webapp by git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment). And your issue will be solved. If also have error when deploy, [you can check the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758223/how-to-deploy-an-azure-webapp-nodejs/62771174#62771174) in `Action` on git.

Comment: 1. This is what is set in the app
2. I'm well aware of how ports work
3. Code is in GitHub and Deployed through deployment centre to both Heroku and Azure web app from the same codebase.